# I am using shelve to append and add to dictionaries, but it won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, shelve

```
import shelve
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
reg = input(Please enter the registration plate: ')
speed = input(Please enter the speed: ')
Dictionary = {name:{reg:speed}}

db = shelve.open('Data')
db['Stuff'].append(Dictionary)
db.close

f = shelve.open('Data', 'r')
print(f['Stuff'])
f.close()
```

I am not sure how to append the dictionary `'Stuff'`. If someone could tell me how to append a dictionary using `shelve` as I have no clue.

Comment: Could you offer a clearer problem description than *"it won't work"*? Also, your example won't run, as there is a missing quote mark.

Comment: `db['Stuff'].append(Dictionary)` would only work if `db['Stuff']` is a list. Evidently, thats not the case if you say it does not work. You can simply _assign_ things to your shelve, e.g. `db['Stuff'] = Dictionary`. This is covered by the official docs, please read and try out things on your own in the interactive interpreter before asking questions on SO. Your code also has multiple other issues: you're missing parens on `db.close`, and `Dictionary` is a bad name for a dict - don't start variable names with uppercase, and use names reflecting the content of the variables, not their types.

Answer (score 1):

```
import shelve
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
reg = input('Please enter the registration plate: ')
speed = input('Please enter the speed: ')
Dictionary = {name:{reg:speed}}

db = shelve.open('Data')
db['Stuff'].append(Dictionary)
db.close

f = shelve.open('Data', 'r')
print(f['Stuff'])
f.close()
```